# Marshmallow incorrect loading with 'Unknown field

Tags: python, marshmallow

When I try to load data with Marshmallow, I get only the part of data, without Nested info.
For this data

```
  self.users [key] = {
                                "full_name": d[0],
                                "email": d[2],
                                "age": d[3],
                                "address_street": d[4],
                                "address_city": d[5],
                                "address_country": d[6],
                                "phone_number": d[7]
    
                        }
```

after loading

try:
serialized_data = serializer_inst.loads(users)
print(serialized_data)
except ValidationError as err:
print(err)

I'm getting only key values :

{'sherlock': ['Unknown field.'], 'doll': ['Unknown field.']}

My serializer:
from marshmallow import fields, Schema, validate, post_load, pre_load, pre_dump, validates

```
class PersonSchema(Schema):
    full_name = fields.Str()
    email = fields.Email()
    age = fields.Integer()
    address_street = fields.Str()
    address_country = fields.Str()
    address_city = fields.Str()
    phone_number = fields.Str()
```

Please help me understand, how to get input from the Nested values

Answer (score 0):

The problem with Nested values - solved.

Comment: If you found a solution, please share your solution here in order to help others with your same problem

Answer (score 0):

Sure, I just changed the structure of dictionary to type without dynamic key:

```
self.users = {"full_name": d[0],
              "email": d[2],
              "age": d[3],
              "address_street": d[4],
              "address_city": d[5],
              "address_country": d[6],
              "phone_number": d[7]}
```